# change the style of default title in stage using javafx

Tags: javafx

I want to change the style of title in stage but i couldn't find anything.
I tried some css codes like:

```
 .title {
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-family: "B Homa";
}
```

but it didn't work for me.I searched about the style of window in javafx and I figured it out that the default style of every native window is Decorated and for designing a custom window I must use UNDERCOATED mode, but I just want to change the size and font style of native window (different font and size) .

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible with a decorated default window. The window itself is a native window from your OS. For example on windows the window implementation is:

com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinWindowand

the title is managed in a native method:

@Override native protected boolean _setTitle(long ptr, String title);

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can change the title with primarystage.settitle(string e), but I want to change the font style (for example from Arial to Times New Roman) and font size( for example from 10pt to 18pt) of native window. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: A undecorated window would work. Have a look at the following project: https://github.com/in-sideFX/Undecorator

Comment: It is awesome.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Muskan Undecorator is no longer being actively developed. It has been replaced by a newer version, called [UndecoratorBis](https://github.com/in-sideFX/UndecoratorBis).